# Running a nodeJS function from the front end index.html to send input data

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm looking for suggestions on my code that'll help with my understanding of rendering html and calling back functions that are within the hosted index.js file. I'm currently calling a function within the node server but i'd like to pass user inputted variables from a front end form that'll call the function the same way.

I can already reference a google sheets page and call the addRow("row#", "{key:index}") function which adds the inputted variables to the excel page. How can I call this same command while outside the scope of the actual document?

```
doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds, function(err) {

    //get all te rows and shit
    doc.getRows(1, function (err, rows) {
        console.log(rows.length);
    })
//this is a test call of the function which works- I now want to pass it in variables from a user inputted form. 
    submitInfo(doc, 'tabletop fun', 'to have fun', '30', 'will do homework', 'TRUE', '50', 'FALSE')

    //call this when a form is submitted
    function submitInfo(doc, activity, description, time, task_for_completion, experience, amount, completed) {
        doc.getRows(1, function(err, rows) {

            nextRow = rows.length+1;

            doc.addRow(1, { activityID: nextRow, activity: activity, description: description, time: time, task_for_completion: task_for_completion, experience:experience, amount:amount, completed:completed}, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);

                }
            })
        })
    }
})
```

http://prntscr.com/o4nhwv

Comment: I'm assuming you've just started doing web development. So I think you don't realise this yet but you "simple" question is actually very broad and would need to cover several chapters on web development: browser scripting, html, http, server development, forms, ajax etc. It's actually less confusing if you started with some other language for server development like PHP or Python since it won't confuse you about the fact that browser script and server code are not the same program and even run on different machines

Comment: Where is the `useServiceAccountAuth` defined? In front-end scripts or back-end node.js code?

Comment: @slebetman its in the file that I call to create the node server "node index.js"